# Facebook Login with Read and Publish Permission

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I'm able to get Read Permission with `logInWithReadPermissions` at the time of Login and it's working fine but whenever i required publish permission,

I'm asking Publish Permission by calling `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(publish_permissions));` but not able to get Permission,
Everytime got `onCancel()` method trigger. No error nothing.

**NOTE** : already loggenIn with read permission, when i'm going to ask publish permission.

Have tried lot solutions, facebook docs many questions nothing works for me can anyone tell me what i'm missing or where i'm doing mistake?.

Here is my Login code :

```
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_hometown", "user_location", "user_friends");

        LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(mActivity, permissionNeeds);
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookResponse();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancel: ");
                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException facebookException) {
                facebookException.printStackTrace();
                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookError();
            }
        });
```

And below code to ask Publish Permission

```
String[] publish_permissions = {"publish_actions"};

        LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(mActivity, Arrays.asList(publish_permissions));
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookResponse();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancel: ");
                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException facebookException) {
                facebookException.printStackTrace();
                mFacebookResultListener.onFacebookError();
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciate.

I'm using : **compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'**

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does the variable `publish_permissions` contain?

Comment: it contains permission : `publish_actions`